# Getting "bash: XXX: command not found" in VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: stud]

I am getting this error on my VS Code terminal. I have tried reinstalling the IDE but it did not go away. I am using Linux mint.

Comment: What happens when you open a Bash terminal *outside* of VS Code? Most likely, it is not a problem with the IDE, but with your bash profile. VS Code, by default, just [uses your system's underlying shell](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration) + whatever `terminal.integrated.shell` settings you added. Check that your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` is valid.

Comment: in my linux terminal everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

This [VScode issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9484#issuecomment-234347728) they say "By default the VS Code integrated terminal does not run as a login shell".

As this is n answer from 2016, the option they give is deprecated.

The problem I has is running the terminal in WSL environment and what worked for me is to add the following to my setting.json:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
            "args": [
                "--login"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to delete the open terminal (the dustbin icon) and reopen. Or just restart VScode.

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening when u are trying to run .sh file, if so then for running a .sh file in vscode execute in this way

```
./scriptname.sh
```

Hope this will help you as this worked for me.